# Task queue works from view, but UnknownQueueError when run from unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

**Updated**: Originally I didn't realize this only fails when run from unit tests.

I have a working task queue in AppEngine with Python.

- When calling a view manually, the task is added to the queue and runs
- When called from unit tests, adding the task to the queue fails with an **UnknownQueueError**.

When reading about others who've encountered the [UnknownQueueError](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/b9f6b64a0208b229) issue, there have been some suggestions of overriding `taskqueue_stub` to fix this. But I'm not sure exactly how this should be done or why.

Comment: The page you linked to has a solution right up the top. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes - that's why I linked there, but it doesn't show anything actually using the taskqueue_stub variable he creates. Nor does it say what's being stubbed out compared to the full version.

Comment: The stub is part of the SDK's internal plumbing. You're simply modifying the existing one to tell it where to find your configuration files. It's a stub because it implements a local emulation of the production task queue service.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your help. I've posted the what I believe to be a completed version of the code as an non-working answer below. Setting taskqueue_stub._root_path to the dir containing queue.yaml as a string, but it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: working answer. My problem was adding the stub fix in an individual unit test: moving it to setUp() fixed things.

In tests.py

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
import os

class BlahTest(MyAppTestCase)
    def setUp(self):
        '''Ensure dev appserver task queue knows where to find queue.yaml'''
        taskqueue_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub( 'taskqueue' ) 
        dircontainingqueuedotyaml = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname( __file__ ))
        taskqueue_stub._root_path = dircontainingqueuedotyaml
```

This now works.

Comment: A simpler and cleaner version using Google App Engine Testbed: ```self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub(root_path=dircontainingqueuedotyaml)```

Comment: I would *highly* recommend against using _root_path as this is a protected attribute.

Comment: Using `root_path` worked for me, wasn't working without it. :)

Comment: It seems `root_path` is required for the taskqueue stub to find the `queue.yaml` file. Here's a snippet from the docstring:  
`root_path: Root path to the directory of the application which may contain a queue.yaml file. If None, then it's assumed no queue.yaml file is available.`